# Notations in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be differential map. We denote tangent map 
$$f_*:TM\rightarrow TN$$
and cotangent map 
$$f^*:T^*N\rightarrow T^*M$$

Now let $M$, $N$ be Riemannian manifolds, and $i:M\rightarrow N$ be an isometric immersion.

> In my textbook, it consider the
>   $$i^*TN=TM\oplus T^\perp M$$

I think it has some mistakes, and the right form is 
$$TN=i_*TM\oplus T^\perp M$$

Can someone help me clarify the confusion?

Comment: $i^\ast TN$ denotes the pullback of the bundle $TN$ via the map $i$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle. It has a different meaning than the map $i^\ast : T^\ast N \longrightarrow T^\ast M$ and in particular does not mean the image of $TN$ under the map $i^\ast: T^\ast N \longrightarrow T^\ast M$ (which does not make sense).

Comment: @HenryT.Horton How about my understanding: $T_{i(p)}N=i_*(T_pM)\oplus T^\perp_p M$?